# The decomposition forms of primes in $A_5$-fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, number-fields, ramification

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $5$ whose Galois closure (over $\mathbb{Q}$) has the Galois group $A_5$, the alternating group of degree five. Is there any result concerning the decomposition forms of a ramified prime $p$ in $K/\mathbb{Q}$? Indeed, I am looking for a result similar to the one given by H. Cohen (Advanced Topics in Computational Number Theory, H. Cohen, Prop. 10.1.26) for the prime decomposition forms in dihedral extensions of number fields.

Thanks for your help